# How to print JavaScript variable dynamically in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm building Notification using Pusher, and I receive 'route' to some page as a JavaScript variable

Now I want to inject this variable to the Notification bar as a link to some page determined in the variable,
I try to make href and put the the route in it using laravel url method to access it from any page. here's the code

```
channel.bind('App\\Events\\Councilcreated', function (data) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", "{{ url(".data.page.") }}");
});
```

the Problem is that printed (data.page) as string not as the value of the (data.page) variable

Comment: Please can you show where you're setting `page` in your event class?

Comment: `
    public $councilname;
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $d;
    public $message;
    public $page;
    public $icon;    
public function __construct($councilname,$id,$title,$message,$page,$icon)
    {
         $d=0;
        $this->councilname = $councilname;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->message  = $message;
        $this->page  = $page;
        $this->icon  = $icon;  
}`

Comment: it printed successfully in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to first store your URL into a javascript variable then add your data into it and then set it to you href. something like below.

```
var url = "{{ url() }}";
a.setAttribute("href", url+'/'+data.page);
```

If you getting htmlspecialchars () error like you said and then use it like below

```
    var url = "{!! url() !!}";
a.setAttribute("href", url+'/'+data.page);
```

Why you not passing full url from php side and directly use it here , something like below.

```
//php
$this->page = url($page);

//javascipt
a.setAttribute("href", data.page);
```

Comment: the frst sugget return laravel exception 
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: I save the page in notification table, Is that correct  to save whole url ?

Comment: don't save it in table just give retrun form your event whole url like i suggest `$this->page = url($page);`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as you're mixing javascript with php i.e. when this function executes you won't have access to the `url` function as it will be executing in the browser.

I would suggest making `page` a fully qualified url in your event class i.e. using the `url()` function in there:

```
public function __construct($councilname, $id, $title, $message, $page, $icon)
{
    $d = 0;
    $this->councilname = $councilname;
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->page = url($page); // <-- This line
    $this->icon = $icon;
}
```

Then in your JS event listener you would just need:

```js
channel.bind('App\\Events\\Councilcreated', function (data) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", data.page);
});
```

Comment: I save the page in notification table in DB, Is that correct to save whole url ?

Comment: @SamehMohamedOmar Yeah, there's nothing wrong with saving the whole URL for the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

In your footer declare a variable like this

`const url = "{{ url() }}";`

In case any special character is being returned, use this:

`const url = "{!! url() !!}";`

and then keep using this variable at all the required places like this:

`a.setAttribute("href", url+'/'+data.page);`

Comment: return laravel exception 
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Must be some special character which your `url()` method is returning. I've updated the answer.